# Meta Tags Inside MasterPage Output On One Line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, master-pages, meta-tags

I like clean code and I'm sure most developers do.  I am coming across an issue where my Meta tags are all appearing on ONE line all together and not on separate lines.

I have a file called "client.master" and here is code for the header:

```
<head runat="server">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

   <script src="/scripts/script1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/scripts/script2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/home-screen.png" />
   <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/images/home-startup.png" />
   <link href="/css/thirdparty/xxxxx.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="/css/design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="headContent" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

That looks very clean and nice.  However, when I view the source of the page, the output shows the `<meta>` tags and the `<link>` tags all on one line.  ***The script tags are not***.

Here is the output of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" /><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

   <script src="/scripts/script1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/scripts/script2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/home-screen.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/images/home-startup.png" /><link href="/css/thirdparty/xxxxx.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="/css/design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

   <title>
      Login
</title></head>
```

Notice the `<meta>` and `<link>` tags are both on a single line **AND** the `<title>` tag has line breaks.

Here is the HTML for the default.aspx page for the Title:

```
<asp:Content ID="title" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="title">
   Login
</asp:Content>
```

My assumption is because the `<meta>` tags and `<link>` tags are self enclosed and the `<script>` tags end with `</script>`.

Is the only way to resolve this issue to close my `<meta>` tags with `</meta>`.  Which way is to be considered the standard when closing meta and link tags? or script tags?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to follow the spec, `link` and `meta` are `void` elements, they *can't* have a closing tag, if your `DOCTYPE` is HTML5, you can use the selfclosing tag `<meta ..../>` but the default way would be to use it only as a start tag, that is a correct conforming use as `empty` elements *don't need* an end tag (`void` ones, as I said, *can't* have it).

Script is not a `void` element, but is an `empty` one, so you can use only the start tag, the self-closing tag or both start and end tags.

Note that for an element to have a content model of type empty really means it **may** be empty, not that it should; that would probably be what it is called `void`.

As to why the asp parser does that to your metas, I can't think of a reason. I understand your preference for clean code, but if it is of any help, try to think that at least that bug contributes to a filesize decrease :o)

Bear in mind that all of this applies to HTML5, XHTML treats void and empty models differently.